# How to add multiple RSS feeds

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, rss

I am struggling to find a way to add multiple RSS Feed URL to be parsed in my code. So far I am able to parse one. I have tried adding an array, but it doesnt seem to work. Please help

```js
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import RSSParser from "rss-parser";

const feedURL = ["https://yaleclimateconnections.org/feed/", "https://rss2.feedspot.com/https://www.climatelinks.org/blog?context=3710842201"];
const parser = new RSSParser();
let articles = [];

const parse = async url => {
    const feed = await parser.parseURL(url);

    feed.items.forEach(item => {
        articles.push({ item })
    })
}

parse(feedURL);

let app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(articles);
})

const server = app.listen("4000", () => {
    console.log("App is listening at http://localhost:4000");
})

export default server;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here...

1. `feedURL` is an array but `parse` expects a single URL string
2. You aren't waiting for your requests to resolve so using `res.send(articles)` may result in an incomplete result

To solve both, create a promise that resolves with all the feeds

```js
// renamed to be plural
const feedUrls = [
  "https://yaleclimateconnections.org/feed/",
  "https://rss2.feedspot.com/https://www.climatelinks.org/blog?context=3710842201",
];

const parser = new RSSParser();
const feedsPromise = Promise.all(feedUrls.map((url) => parser.parseURL(url)));
```

then make sure you wait for that to resolve before responding to requests

```js
app.get("/", async (_req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.send(
      (await feedsPromise).flatMap(({ items }) =>
        items.map((item) => ({ item }))
      )
    );
  } catch (err) {
    next(err); // pass any errors to the error handler
  }
});
```

Comment: tried what you have mentioned, but didnt work... error goes back to 'map'

Comment: @mtan006 what _error_?

Comment: TypeError: feedURL.map is not a function
[1]     at file:///C:/Users/tanma/Desktop/world-space-game/desktop-gui/rss-server/index.js:9:42
[1]     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)

Comment: @mtan006 note I've renamed it to `feedUrls` but even without that, it's still an array so will definitely have a `map()` function

Comment: ReferenceError: feedUrls is not defined
[1]     at file:///C:/Users/tanma/Desktop/world-space-game/desktop-gui/rss-server/index.js:11:36
[1]     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)

Comment: @mtan006 just a typo (`feedURLs` vs `feedUrls`), fixed  now